# Reindexing the composition of two families of elements of a group

Tags: induction, index-notation

Let $n,m\in\mathbb{N}_{>0}$ and let $(x_{i})_{i\in[1,m]}$ and $(y_{j})_{j\in[1,n]}$ be two families of elements of a group $G$ whose law is written multiplicatively. How can I rewrite the composition
$$\prod_{i=1}^{m} x_{i}\cdot(\prod_{j=1}^{n} y_{j})^{-1}$$
as a family of elements of $G$ over the interval $[1,m+n]$? I know that for
$$\prod_{i=1}^{m} x_{i}\cdot(\prod_{j=1}^{n} y_{j})$$
I have $(z_{k})_{k\in[1,m+n]}$ such that
$$\prod_{k=1}^{m+n} z_{k}=\prod_{i=1}^{m} x_{i}\cdot(\prod_{j=1}^{n} y_{j}),$$ 
where 
\begin{equation*}
    z_k=
    \begin{cases}
      x_k, &  1\leq k\leq m; \\
      y_{k-m}, & m+1\leq k\leq m+n.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}

I tried defining a function $u$ such that
\begin{equation*}
    u_k=
    \begin{cases}
      x_k, &  1\leq k\leq m; \\
      y_{(n+1)-(k-m)}, & m+1\leq k\leq m+n.
    \end{cases}
\end{equation*}
but I ran into a problem whilst trying to show that 
$$(\prod_{j=1}^{n} y_{j})^{-1}=\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n} y_{(n+1)-(k-m)}^{-1};$$
specifically, for the inductive step (induction over $n$ with $m$ fixed) we have 
$$\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+(n+1)} y_{((n+1)+1)-(k-m)}^{-1}=\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n} y_{((n+1)+1)-(k-m)}^{-1}\cdot y^{-1}_{1},$$
but the expression $\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n} y_{((n+1)+1)-(k-m)}^{-1}$ is different from what's assumed for $n$: namely $\prod_{k=m+1}^{m+n} y_{(n+1)-(k-m)}^{-1}$.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, I'd do it step-by-step. If $m=n$ then

$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}x_i\left(\prod_{j=1}^{m}y_j\right)^{-1} = \prod_{k=1}^{m}x_ky_k^{-1}.$$

If $m\gt n$ then

$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}x_i\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}y_j\right)^{-1} = \prod_{i=1}^{m-n}x_i\prod_{l=1}^{n}x_{l+m-n}\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}y_j\right)^{-1} = \prod_{i=1}^{m-n}x_i\prod_{k=1}^{n}x_{k+m-n}y_k^{-1}.$$

If $m\lt n$ then

$$\prod_{i=1}^{m}x_i\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n}y_j\right)^{-1} = \prod_{i=1}^{m}x_i\left(\prod_{j=1}^{n-m}y_j\prod_{l=1}^{m}y_{l+n-m}\right)^{-1} = \prod_{j=1}^{n-m}y_j\prod_{k=1}^{m}x_ky_{k+n-m}^{-1}.$$

Finally, try to combine all chances in one $\prod_{k=1}^{m+n}z_{k}$.